# starting a text chat with google hangouts with a url like in skype

Tags: url, google-talk

I want to create a button or link in my web application for starting a chat to a contact.

I know the contact's google addresses, and I want to include in a web page, a list of the possible destinations (like a contact list) which the user can click and automatically start a chat window to this user (assuming the user has the hangouts plugin installed and logged-in).

With skype, I can include something like <a href="skype:someuserl">call someuser1</a>. How do I do the same thing with Hangouts?

Answer (score 0):

Google has something called the Hangout Button which you can embed into your website. More information on how to embed it can be found at: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button

Comment: I was checking this, but I can't find the any way for adding a destination address to the button in order to directly start a chat. The button opens hangouts and tells the user he is starting a new video call and asks for adding people.

I don't understand why google didn't include an option so usefull like skype's "skype:xxx" uri.